# Does memory hierarchy implementation uses both temporal and spatial locality?

Tags: cpu-architecture

I know that a program uses both temporal and spatial locality. 
  But how about the implementation of a computer memory in a memory hierarchy form? I was sure that only the temporal memory is used but the wiki about "Spatial and temporal locality usage" is pretty vague and it confused me.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, there's no such thing as temporal memory (unless you mean volatile memory?). Temporal and spatial locality are artifacts of a program access pattern,  some architectures may be "friendlier" towards such patterns due to memory layout and cache usage.

Comment: Spatial locality is provided by caches storing data in blocks larger than the typical size for a single access (e.g., 64 byte blocks vs. 8 or 4 byte typical access size). The entire block of data is retrieved speculating that there will be spatial locality in the program, that other data in that block will be accessed in the near future. (Address translation also exploits spatial locality though at a larger granularity. DRAM is organized in rows which can benefit from locality of access.)

Comment: I was referring to temporal locality as in  "Hierarchical memory is a hardware optimization that takes the benefits of spatial and temporal locality and can be used on several levels of the memory hierarchy." [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference) .  I am doing quizes from an old book and the answer in the book is "In a memory hierarchy implementation, the only technique used is temporal locality" which according to that quote is wrong.

Comment: `In a memory hierarchy implementation` sounds like nonsense, unless you define that term to mean something more specific than normal.  Also, once you understand anything about caches and cache lines, these statements would be obvious, and you wouldn't have to puzzle out the language they use, or try to memorize facts without understanding what they really mean.  A good start might be http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/cpumemory.pdf